# TeamCity wont create release folder

Tags: c#, msbuild, teamcity

When using TeamCity and running a build I get the following error message.

```
13:20:31]Step 1/1: MSBuild (1s)
[13:20:32][Step 1/1] src\DystopiaOnline.proj.teamcity: Build target: BuildSolution
[13:20:32][src\DystopiaOnline.proj.teamcity] BuildSolution
[13:20:32][BuildSolution] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8c8eb5050252f271\src\DystopiaOnline.proj(36, 5): error MSB4062: The "DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks.GetUnixTimestamp" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8c8eb5050252f271\src\DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks/bin/Release/DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8c8eb5050252f271\src\DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks\bin\Release\DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
[13:20:32][Step 1/1] Step MSBuild failed
```

However when I run the build from the developer command prompt the build works fine. Taking a look inside the `C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8c8eb5050252f271\src\D ystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks\bin` only shows a Debug folder rather than a Release folder. Running the build from the developer command prompt works ok just building from Team City doesn't.

[image]

shouldn't the Release folder be created when the build is run from Team City with the Env variable set to prod? what could be causing this? Anyone any ideas?

In my project solution .proj file have the following conditions set to determine a build configuration. can anyone with any experience working with team city offer any advice as to what the problem may be? thanks.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
        <Env Condition="'$(Env)' == ''">dev</Env>
        <VersionNumber Condition="'$(VersionNumber)' == ''">1</VersionNumber>
        <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)/Tasks</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
        <UnityPath Condition="'$(UnityPath)' == ''">c:\Program Files (x86)\Unity</UnityPath>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Env)' == 'dev'">
        <BuildConfig>Debug</BuildConfig>
        <Domain>mmo.dystopiaOnline.dev</Domain>
        <SetParamsFile>Parameters.Local.config</SetParamsFile>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Env)' == 'prod'">
        <BuildConfig>Release</BuildConfig>
        <Domain>mmo.DystopiaOnline.com</Domain>
        <SetParamsFile>Parameters.Production.config</SetParamsFile>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Env)' == 'sta'">
        <BuildConfig>Release</BuildConfig>
        <Domain>mmo.DystopiaOnline.sta</Domain>
        <SetParamsFile>Parameters.Staging.config</SetParamsFile>
      </PropertyGroup>
```

TeamCity build log

```
[11:45:53]Checking for changes
[11:45:53]Collecting changes in 1 VCS root (1s)
[11:45:55]Clearing temporary directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[11:45:55]Publishing internal artifacts
[11:45:55]Checkout directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8c8eb5050252f271
[11:45:55]Updating sources: server side checkout
[11:45:55]Step 1/1: MSBuild (4s)
[11:45:55][Step 1/1] Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MsBuildBootstrap.exe /workdir:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8c8eb5050252f271 "/msbuildPath:C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\MSBuild.exe"
[11:45:55][Step 1/1] in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8c8eb5050252f271
[11:45:59][Step 1/1] src\DystopiaOnline.proj.teamcity: Build target: BuildSolution
[11:45:59][src\DystopiaOnline.proj.teamcity] BuildSolution
[11:45:59][BuildSolution] MSBuild
[11:45:59][BuildSolution] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8c8eb5050252f271\src\DystopiaOnline.proj(36, 5): error MSB4062: The "DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks.GetUnixTimestamp" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8c8eb5050252f271\src\DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks/bin/Release/DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8c8eb5050252f271\src\DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks\bin\Release\DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
[11:45:59][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 1
[11:45:59][Step 1/1] MSBuild output
[11:45:59][Step 1/1] Step MSBuild failed
[11:45:59]Publishing internal artifacts
[11:45:59]Build finished
```

This is how my project setup look witht the build folder.

[image]

[image]

[link to .proj file on OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=70CCBA0DA75EAAB7%21108)

Error after copying release file into TeamCity manually

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3797, 5): error MSB3027: Could not copy "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8c8eb5050252f271\src\DystopiaOnline.Base\bin\Release\DystopiaOnline.Base.dll" to "bin\Release\DystopiaOnline.Base.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3797, 5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8c8eb5050252f271\src\DystopiaOnline.Base\bin\Release\DystopiaOnline.Base.dll" to "bin\Release\DystopiaOnline.Base.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Release\DystopiaOnline.Base.dll' because it is being used by another process.
```

Comment: Is the project that should produce \src\DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks/bin/Release/DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks.dll running as part of this overall build? If so, what is the build log output for it. Or where should that file be coming from?

Comment: Hi Nanhydrin thanks for taking the time to help, the \src\DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks/bin/Release/DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks.dll is part of a virtual build folder within my soloution

Comment: What do you mean a virtual build folder? Is there build log output showing the file being created at the specified location?

Comment: I mean that the build folder only exists on my local machine, as I understand it a release or debug folder should be created depeneding if i run a dev build or production build from TeamCity. In this case I'm running a production build by seeting the env value in TeamCity to prod. however this only creates a debug folder but should be creating a release folder.

Comment: I added the TeamCity build log.

Comment: When you run the build locally from the developer command prompt what is the line that you're using? Are you sure that TeamCity is calling the same project and target when it runs. What build project is trying to use DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks.GetUnixTimestamp build task, is it the solution file or DystopiaOnline.proj?

Comment: Hi Nanhydrin it is DystopiaOnline.proj that is trying to use DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks.GetUnixTimestamp. the command i am running from the developer commad prompt is "msBuild DystopiaOnline.proj /t:DeployWebsite /p:WebDeployComputer=mmo.DystopiaOnline.sta /p:WebDeployUser=deploy /p:WebDeployPassword=TEST /p:Env=prod"

Comment: In most standard C# builds it's the Configuration parameter to the build that controls the output you get. Does your Env=prod have a knock on effect somewhere that sets Configuration=Release?

Comment: It seems like the configuration parameter is not being sent to the build, or at least that's what I think is happening, I really stumped at this and at the verge of giving up.

Comment: You say that you're running the DeployWebsite build target, is there another target that you run before that that should build all the binaries? Or should it also build the binaries? Basically I don't think you can reference a build task in the Build.Tasks project, you have to reference the built dll. And it's not clear where that project is being built before you're attempting to use the GetUnixTimestamp task.

Comment: The binaries should build along with the website, I went ahead and copied the release folder manually into the TeamCity build folder to see if it would get a successful build and I get a different error this time. I added the error  the original post. it seems that the file is locked in some way. I've checked all the permission on the file  and also checked to see if the are being used, but they are not, this just gets more confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your DystopiaOnline.proj file in the word "Configuraton":

```
<MSBuild Projects="DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks/DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks.csproj" Properties="Configuraton=$(BuildConfig)" />
```

I think that this is the reason of the incorrect configuration building.

Comment: Wow thank you Alina that fixed it great attention to detail, cant believe I missed that, Thanks to Nanhydrin, Carnifex and JonSquared also for taking time to help.

Answer (score 0):

How have you setup the parameter in the build? It's most likely that it's value is not being passed to the build runner so it defaults to dev

```
<Env Condition="'$(Env)' == ''">dev</Env>
```

If you are using teamcity parameters it should be a system or environment parameter. You can also check the parameters used in a build by clicking on it and going to the parameters tabs, might want to double check that it has the value you want.

Comment: Hi Jon thanks for the input I have set the TeamCity environment parameters to "prod" this is my first time using TeamCity, I may have set them up wrong so I went back and double checked them however the error still remains.

Answer (score 0):

First keep in mind, that Windows path is '\' NOT '/'. In normal cases there is not any different (eg. when you want to put path in Explorer), but sometimes (I run in to some problems with some task in MsBuild) the mechanism doesn't recognize that this is proper path. So change the path to

```
 <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\Tasks\</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
```

(Also MsBuild convention told us to put trailing slash)

And whenever you have reference to "DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks.dll": `[...]src\DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks\bin\Release\DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks.dll`.

---

In the build log, there is not any sign that the MsBuild try to build the `DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks`. HOW you specify the order of building your projects? Can you add this project that we can see exactly what MsBuild want to do and in what order.

If you use `<UsingTask>` inside the same project file that want to build `DystopiaOnline.Build.Tasks`... It will never work, because MsBuild first try to resolve task and then run targets to build.

It could work on your machine when you already build the project but not in clean environment when there is not (yet) any task.

Comment: Hi Carnifex tanks for taking the time to respond. I changed all the backslashes as you suggested, hover the error still occurs in TeamCity. I added a copy of the proj file to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

try creating new system parameter called system.Configuration and set value "Release"